# Determine whether or not $x^5 +5x^2 + 1$ irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether or not $x^5 +5x^2 + 1$ irreducible over $\Bbb Q$.

I can see that by the mod $p$ test with $p$ = $5$, the polynomial reduces to $x^5 + 1$, but from here I can't determine its (ir)reducibility.  I know that $4$ is a zero here, but the only theorem I know that the $0$'s determine irreducibility are for deg $f(x) = 2$ or $3$.

Comment: That reduction is **really a reduction**: $\;x^5+5x^2+1=x^5+1=(x+1)^5\pmod5\;$ .

Comment: I'm confused, does that mean that it's reducible since each $(x+1)$ is irreducible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The polynomial $x^5+5x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$, hence it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, too.

To prove the former fact, we just need to check that $x^2+x+1$ is not a divisor of $x^5+x^2+1$, pretty straightforward, since over $\mathbb{F}_2$
$$ x^5+x^2+1 \equiv 1 \pmod{x^2+x+1}.$$

Comment: Why does checking whether or not $x^2 + x + 1$ and no others is a divisor of $x^5 + x^2 + 1$ determine $x^5+x^2+1$'s irreducibility?

Comment: It has no root in $ \mathbb F_2 $, and since it is a quintic, it must split as the product of an irreducible quadratic and an irreducible cubic if it is reducible. The only irreducible quadratic in $ \mathbb F_2 $ is $ x^2 + x + 1 $, so showing that it doesn't divide our polynomial is enough to rule out this case.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with any theorems involving quintic polynomials, is there a way to explain this without referring to them?  I've only been introduced to the mod $p$ test, maximal ideal iff irreducibility, and Eisenstein's Criterion as irreducibility tests for $n >3$ polynomials.

Comment: @OliverG: Starfall already explained the hidden details here. There is only one irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: I don't understand.  Why is it only an irreducible quadratic and cubic?  Why can't it be $(x^4 + ax^3 + ... + 1) ( x + 1)$?

Comment: @OliverG: in such a case the given polynomial would have a root in $\mathbb{F}_2$, due to the $x+1$ factor, but the given polynomial has trivially no root in $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Why would the existence of a root make this an issue?  Because isn't the product still two non-units?

Comment: @OliverG: $(x+1)$ is a factor of $f(x)$ iff $f(-1)=0$. Since $\mathbb{F}_2$ has only two elements, it is enough to compute $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ to rule out the presence of linear factors.

Comment: So, if a quintic polynomial is reducible but it is not divided by any linear factor, it has to split as the product of an irreducible quadratic polynomial and an irreducible cubic polynomial. But the only irreducible quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $x^2+x+1$ etc.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  So since there are no roots, there are no linear factors, which means $f(x)$ can't be written as two non-units with one being $ax + b$.  Therefore a cubic-quadratic combination is the only to try?

Comment: @OliverG: sure, what else has degree $5$ and no linear factor?

Answer (score 2):

Let us try reduction modulo $\;2\;$, and assume the polynomial is reducible. As it clearly has no roots in $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ , we have

$$x^5+x^2+1=(x^3+ax^2+bx+1)(x^2+rx+1)\implies\begin{cases}r+a=0\\1+ar+b=0\\a+br+1=1\\b+r=0\end{cases}$$

From the first and fourth equations we get $\;a=r=b\;$ . If $\;a=b=r=1;$ , then the second equation gives $\;1+1+1=0\;$ , contradiction, so then $\;a=b=r=0\;$, but again the second equation gives a contradiction, so then the polynomial is irreducible modulo $\;2\;$ and thus irreducible over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ .

The above can be simplified if you know all the irreducible polynomial of low degree over $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ , which are very few...